# ComboBox always filling with System.Data.DataRowView

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

The Code below works to populate the ComboBox drop down with the company name and their address, the problem is that once I actually select a value from the drop down it always just populates the textbox with "System.Data.DataRowView"

Anyone know how to fix this?

[image: Current Implementation]

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,10,0,0" DataContext="{Binding parties}">
    <TextBlock Text="Supplier" Style="{StaticResource tabTextBlock}"/>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Vwr.Table.Tbl, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
      x:Name="Supplier"
      SelectedIndex="{Binding Vwr.Table.GridSelIndex, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
      SelectedItem="{Binding Vwr.Table.Vals[1].Val, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
      IsEditable="True" 

            Style="{StaticResource tabTextBox}"
      >
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock.Text>
                        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{} {0} , {1}">
                            <Binding Path="Name"/>
                            <Binding Path="Address"/>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </TextBlock.Text>
                </TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>

    </ComboBox>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Your SelectedItem is not correctly bound... I imagine you are missing a .Val[index] or you should be using Vwr.Table.Tbl[Vwr.Table.GridSelIndex] .. anyway, without looking at Vwr.Table its difficult to tell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the `TextSearch.TextPath` property to a name of a column in your DataTable:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="Supplier" TextSearch.TextPath="Name" ... />
```

If you want to display both the `Name` and the `Address` of a selected row, you should add a column to your `DataTable`:

```
dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Combined", typeof(string), "Name + ', ' + Address"));
```

...and also set the `DisplayMemberPath` property to the name of this column:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Vwr.Table.Tbl, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                      x:Name="Supplier"
                      SelectedIndex="{Binding Vwr.Table.GridSelIndex, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding Vwr.Table.Vals[1].Val, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                      IsEditable="True" 
                      Style="{StaticResource tabTextBox}"
                      DisplayMemberPath="Combined" TextSearch.TextPath="Combined">
</ComboBox>
```

Using an `ItemTemplate` is not a solution.